# Verifying the presence of an image inside of a textbox using SmartBear TestComplete with JScript

Tags: css, jscript, testcomplete

I am testing a web application using JScript in TestComplete and need to verify that a WordWheel TextBox includes an image of a magnifying glass inside of it. And that when text is entered, a red x appears over the magnifying glass. See the image below. I dont need to know what the image looks like, just need to maybe find a property I can use to verify that it exists. Or maybe more properties to verify that the red X appears, etc.

For design reference, this is how I verify the text font style of that text box below:

```
if (searchTextBox.currentStyle.fontStyle == "italic" && modulesTextBox.currentStyle.color == "gray")
  {
   Log.Checkpoint("The text box font is gray and italic");
  }
  else
  {
    Log.Error("The text box font is not gray and italic);
  }
```

Is this possible?

EDIT: Well it looks like I need 10 reputations to post images. How do I get reputations? In the meantime, I can email the picture in question.

Comment: I think using a CSS selector may work, but I tried and its telling me "The CSS selector element was not found.". I have tried different CSS Selectors such as CSS Selector = "h3"; and other ones. How do I know which CSS selector to use?

Comment: Put the HTML code of the text box and the needed images to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use TestComplete's QuerySelector method to find the needed object by its CSS attributes. For example:

```
//JScript
CSSSelector = "div#main-nav a[target=blank]"; 
res=TestedPage.QuerySelector(CSSSelector);
```

This article contains additional information you may need:

http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/55769/